# Can I convert this for loop to an $.each loop?

Tags: json, jquery

I have the following script which works fine:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'serverside_script',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Error: ' + status + '\nError Text: ' + error + '\nResponse Text: ' + xhr.responseText);
    },
    success: function(results) {
        var len = results.length; 

        for(i=0; i<len; i++) { 
            $("#tabs").tabs("add","tabs.aspx?tab=" + results[i].key, results[i].value)
        };
    }
});
```

Is it possible to convert the for loop to a more jquery type $.each loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why yes it is. The function provided can take up to two arguments: first the key, and finally the individual object being iterated.

```
$.each(results, function(i, obj) {
    $("#tabs").tabs("add","tabs.aspx?tab=" + obj.key, obj.value)
});
```

See [the reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for more information on the jQuery.each function.

Answer (score 1):

for better performance :

```
var tabs = $("#tabs");
$.each(results, function(index, item) {
    tabs.tabs("add","tabs.aspx?tab=" + item.key, item.value);
});
```

Executing $("#tabs") each time is not necessary.

Comment: +1 for caching the `$("#tabs")` selection. Re-running it inside the loop is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(results, function(index, item) {
  $("#tabs").tabs("add","tabs.aspx?tab=" + item.key, item.value)
});
```